# View Bills No Paid for the Month

Tags: sql, oracle

my objective is to view the bills that have not been paid for the month SEP/2012

```
create view Viewe as
  select companyname,salutation,firstname,lastname, billingadd, billing.latestatus
  from CUSTOMER, CUST_NONRES, BILLING
  where cust_nonres.customerid = billing.custid
  and to_date(to_char(billingdate, 'MON-YYYY')) = to_date('092012', 'MON-YYYY')
  and PAID = 'NO';
```

here is my error when i select * from viewe

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected
>   01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
>   *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
>              incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
>              required by the format model.
>   *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
>              elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

Thanks for your help.

---

I had change it to :

```
create view Viewe as
select companyname,salutation,firstname,lastname, billingadd, billingdate, billing.latestatus, amount
from CUSTOMER, CUST_NONRES, BILLING
where cust_nonres.customerid = billing.custid
and customer.customerid = cust_nonres.customerid
and TRUNC(billingdate, 'MM') = to_date('092012', 'MMYYYY')
and PAID = 'NO';
```

--------------------------- UPDATE

Hi Guys, can anyone help me out, how could i possibly sum it up, what syntax could i use to sum the entries generated. Thanks.

Comment: I think that it is correct now - but can't test it, as I don't have the DDL (CREATE TABLE statements, etc). Just a tip: if you ask DB related questions, please include that information, as then it will be very easy for us to test our proposed solutions using [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Hi Chris,
one doubt you are using CUSTOMER table in view ..but this table is not used for joining condition ..so this will lead to cross join with  tables CUST_NONRES,BILLING .. will this make desired output

Comment: @GKV check the update, OP has added the join condition itno the WHERE clause, so now it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
create view Viewe as
select companyname,salutation,firstname,lastname, billingadd, billing.latestatus
from CUSTOMER, CUST_NONRES, BILLING
where cust_nonres.customerid = billing.custid
and TRUNC(billingdate, 'MM') = to_date('092012', 'MMYYYY')
and PAID = 'NO';
```

This would fix the issue of the date error message.

The logic behind is that the `TRUNC` function truncates the date (hence the name) to the specified field. It is probablz much-much faster than converting to string then back to date.

**However** you will get bad results!!! You have **3** tables, and only **1** expression specifying the connections between them! This will give you very strange results (duplications resulting from the cartesian product caused by the unspecified link). I also recommend using `JOIN ON` syntax, as it is far more readable (and the optimizer will take care of it anyway):

```
create view Viewe as
select companyname,salutation,firstname,lastname, billingadd, billing.latestatus
from CUSTOMER
JOIN CUST_NONRES ON cust_nonres.customerid = customer.customerid --this is just a guess
JOIN BILLING ON cust_nonres.customerid = billing.custid
where 
and TRUNC(billing.billingdate, 'MM') = to_date('092012', 'MMYYYY')
and PAID = 'NO';
```

Since I write my queries this way, I never forgot to add the proper expressions for joining the tables, whereas using the WHERE clause for connecting the tables I made a mistake once in a while - and sometimes it did take time to find the mistake.

Also, bear in mind, that if you do a lot of joins like this, you should consider using [Oracle function based indexes](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_function_based_index_2.html), like this one:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_BILLINGDATE_TRUNC_MM ON BILLING(TRUNC(BILLINGDATE,'MM'));
```

As this will *significantly* improve join performance.

Also, depending the volume of the data at hand, you might read up on [partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm).

Recommended reading

- [Oracle TRUNC function for Dates](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php)

Comment: please refer to my update and see if it is what i had edited is a SQL logically correct.